# How do I make this python sorting code modular?

Tags: python, sorting

I've been looking into sorting algorythms and did a very unefficient one myself just to see if I know how to do it at all.

Here's the python code:

```
from random import randint
a = [randint(1,100), randint(1,100), randint(1,100), randint(1,100)]
print("starting value:", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3])
temp = 0
passed = 0

while(passed != 3):
    if(a[0] > a[1]):
        temp = a[0]
        a[0] = a[1]
        a[1] = temp
        print("pass 1:", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3])
    else:
        passed = (passed + 1)
    if(a[1] > a[2]):
        temp = a[1]
        a[1] = a[2]
        a[2] = temp
        print("pass 2:", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3])
    else:
        passed = (passed + 1)
    if(a[2] > a[3]):
        temp = a[2]
        a[2] = a[3]
        a[3] = temp
        print("pass 3:", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3])
    else:
        passed = (passed + 1)
exit()
```

I want to be able to make the number of passes and the input data variable and modular, does anyone have any tips? (please explain your logic behind your solution, I want to learn)
Thank you for your help!

I didn't really try anything yet other than making the array items a variable which didn't work quite well

Answer (score 0):

You can sort using **bubble sort algorithm**:

```
def bubble_sort(lst):
    sort = False
    temp=None
    while not sort:
        sort=True
        for i in range(len(lst)-1):
            if lst[i] > lst[i+1]:
                temp=lst[i+1]
                lst[i],lst[i+1] = lst[i+1], lst[i]
                sort=False
            print(*lst)
        
bubble_sort([randint(1,100), randint(1,100), randint(1,100), randint(1,100)])
```

Sample Output:

```
17 77 41 88
17 41 77 88
17 41 77 88
17 41 77 88
17 41 77 88
17 41 77 88
```